# Getting .html() or .text() from a textarea

Tags: jquery, textarea

I'm have a very annoying issue with a textarea when trying to retrieve its content.

When I call `$('#formMessage').text()` I always get the textarea's original value, doesn't matter how much I write or delete of it, it keeps returning me the original content.

I'm not posting the code because it's really simple. A textarea within a form and let's say an `alert()` to check the textarea's content.

Any idea why this might be happening??

PS: if I try to modify the content by doing `.text('modified content')` it does get modified, and when I ask for the `.text()` it now returns the modified value. What's going on here?

PS: let me know if this isn't clear enough. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The code is never simple, post it!

Comment: i agree. even if it is simple to some people, the value would be greater to someone searching on google and arriving here.

Comment: I agree. However it was as simple as alert( $('#textarea-id').text() );
Thanks to the guys I now know I should have used .val()

Comment: could of been a typo, but how would anyone know

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#formMessage").val()
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the jQuery [.val() function](http://api.jquery.com/val/) instead of `.text()` to get the content of a textarea.

```
<textarea id="formMessage">blah blah</textarea>
```

```
$("#formMessage").val(); // returns "blah blah"
```

Answer (score 2):

"The .text() method cannot be used on input elements. For input field text, use the .val() method."

straight from [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/text/)